# Finding a point on a graph.

Tags: calculus

So my line has the equation:
$y = 4e^{-2x} -e^{-4x}$

Point B on the curve lies on the x axis, and I need to find the x coordinate of B. If it lies on the x axis, then it must occur when y = 0, meaning I now get the equation:

$$
4e^{-2x} -e^{-4x} = 0
$$
$$
4e^{-2x} = e^{-4x}
$$
$$
\text{then I took the natural log of both sides:}
$$
$$
ln4e^{-2x} = lne^{-4x}
$$
$$
\text{Then used the log law to move the powers to the outside of the log}
$$
$$
-2xln(4e) = -4xln(e)
$$
$$
\text{Since }ln(e) = 1:
$$
$$
  -2xln(4e) = -4x
  \text{ but by this point I knew I had made an error.}
$$

I now cannot divide through by x without losing x, and if I do, I hit maths error. I am not sure how to solve the equation when setting it equal to 0.

The previous part of the question was to find $x$ when $e^{-2x} = 4$, but I see no indication that this question asks you to reference that question at all.

Comment: The mistake is when you move the powers to the outside of the log, note that $\ln(4e^{-2x})\ne-2x\ln(4e)$! Because $-2x$ is only the power of $e$ but **not** $4e$ in the LHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $X=e^{-2x}$,

$$4e^{-2x}-e^{-4x}=0\iff 4X-X^2=0\iff X(4-X)=0\iff \begin{cases}X=0\\ X=4\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}e^{-2x}=0\  (impossible)\\ e^{-2x}=4\end{cases}\iff x=-\frac{\ln(4)}{2}=-\ln(2).$$

We conclude that the coordinate of $B$ are $(-\ln(2),0)$.